how to replace every image file name with its image for pdf file? to print all WhatsApp Chats including media
I need help with using VBA to add image into exported text from WhatsApp chats; to include media in appropriate location. With help I made progress but run into extra text appear in Word Document (with which export chat is pasted into) is not recognized by VBA.
Example of word line is "附件? 00000004-PHOTO-2024-10-16-15-39-21.jpg"
but in Folder the file name is "00000004-PHOTO-2024-10-16-15-39-21.jpg
How to match Word Text to File folder fullpathname ?
code as follows
Option Explicit
Sub InsertImagesAllDocuments(TextPlaceHolder As String)
'Sub InsertImagesAllDocuments()
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552141/microsoft-word-macro-vba-replace-text-with-image-in-document-header
Dim n, C As Integer
n = Application.Documents.count
C = 1

Dim r As Range

Windows(C).Activate

Do
Dim imageFullPath As String
Dim FIndText As String
imageFullPath = TextPlaceHolder '"C:\Users\sunny\OneDrive\ruby\dispute\00000004-PHOTO-2024-10-16-15-39-21.jpg"
'FIndText = "TextPlaceholder"
FIndText = imageFullPath
    With Selection
    .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    With .Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = FIndText
        ' Loop until Word can no longer
        ' find the search string, inserting the specified image at each location
        Do While .Execute
            With Selection
                .MoveRight
                With .InlineShapes
                    .AddPicture FileName:=imageFullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                End With
            End With
        Loop

    End With
End With
    C = C + 1
    On Error Resume Next
    Windows(C).Activate

Loop Until C > n



 End Sub

Sub FindBracketedText()
'http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?881-Solved-Finding-Text-Within-Square-Brackets
Dim msg As String

With Selection

.HomeKey wdStory

With .Find

.ClearFormatting
.Format = False

.Text = "\<*.jpg\>"
.Replacement.Text = ""
.MatchWildcards = True

.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindStop

.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False

.Execute

End With

Do

msg = msg & Mid$(Selection, 2, Len(Selection) - 2) & vbNewLine
.Find.Execute
    Dim TrimMsg As String
    TrimMsg = cleanMyString(msg)
    Debug.Print TrimMsg
    InsertImagesAllDocuments TrimMsg
Loop While .Find.Found


End With

MsgBox msg

End Sub

Function cleanMyString(sInput)
'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24048400/function-to-trim-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-vba
    ' Remove leading and trailing spaces
    sInput = Trim(sInput)
    'Remove other characters that you dont want
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(10), "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(13), "")
    sInput = Replace(sInput, Chr(9), "")
    cleanMyString = sInput
End Function


Images:

Export text:

code is pasted into post

This seems to work for me (updated my approach to allow for line breaks inside the file names)
Option Explicit

Sub tester()
    
    Dim filePath As String, fName As String, i As Long
    Dim col As Collection, ref, rng As Range, done As Boolean, allJpg As Collection
    
    filePath = "C:\Temp\pics\"
    Set allJpg = MatchedFiles(filePath, "*.jpg") 'find all .jpg files
    
    'get all possible file references
    Set col = AllPictureReferences(ThisDocument)
    
    For Each ref In col  'loop over found ranges
        Debug.Print "----------------"
        Set rng = ref(0)
        Debug.Print rng.Start, rng.End
        Debug.Print ref(1) 'text with no line beaks
        
        For i = 1 To allJpg.Count
            fName = allJpg(i)
            'is the jpg file name contained in text of this range?
            If InStr(1, ref(1), fName, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Found match: " & fName
                rng.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseEnd
                rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=filePath & fName, _
                      LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                Exit For 'stop checking file names
            End If
        Next i
    Next ref

End Sub

'Scan document for all ranges with text matching "<*.jpg>" and
'  return them in a collection of arrays
Function AllPictureReferences(doc As Document) As Collection
    Dim rng As Range, txt As String, col As Collection
    Set col = New Collection
    Set rng = doc.Range
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "\<*.jpg\>"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .MatchCase = False
        Do While .Execute
            'after Execute, `rng` is now the found text
            txt = Replace(rng.Text, vbLf, "") 'remove line feeds
            txt = Replace(txt, vbCr, "")
            'store the range and the contained text with no line feeds
            col.Add Array(rng.Duplicate, txt)
        Loop
    End With
    Set AllPictureReferences = col
End Function

'Return a collection of any file names at `fPath` which 
'   match `pattern` (e.g. "*.jpg", "*.png" etc)
Function MatchedFiles(ByVal fPath As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim f
    Set MatchedFiles = New Collection
    If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\"
    f = Dir(fPath & pattern, vbNormal)
    Do While Len(f) > 0
        MatchedFiles.Add f
        f = Dir()
    Loop
End Function

Before:

After:


Thanks for support but no image added with existing code; somehow Word has funny characters in front of image file name which is I suspect VBA needs more work. Is there code to match file name by approximation or match trailing part of text is file name in Word? Thanks in advance!

When using .Text = "\<*" & f & "\>" the * should account for any characters in front of the filename.  If that's not working then try a manual search using one of the filenames you know are present in the document and see it it matches.

How to modify code to find file name from Text document which has line feed within it?

You'll need to show an example of what you mean here - I'm not sure what you're asking...   If you want to know how to read from a text file line by line then see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528694/read-parse-text-file-line-by-line-in-vba

thanks for your support. An example of Word opening WhatsApp export file for some reason there is a line feed breaking the filename of the image file. It does not happen to all chats but some. For those chat that do not have line feed breaking the file name, I am still troubleshooting why VBA cannot get those file. The file name and folder path are ok but the image does not get inserted.
[16/10/2024 下午3:39:21] :<附件 00000004-
PHOTO-2024-10-16-15-39-21.jpg>

Try out the new code above - working for me even when there are line breaks in the file name.
